# Issue with Images in GUI python

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I am using python 2.7 and for some reason it doesn't recognize some of the modules. I want to print an image with Tkinter and its just doesn't work.

```html
from Tkinter import *
import ImageTk

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

canvas = Canvas(frame, bg="black", width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Logo.png")
canvas.create_image(150, 150, image=photoimage)

root.mainloop()
```

The error is:

```html
C:\Python27\python.exe D:/Users/user-pc/Desktop/Appland/Project.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/user-pc/Desktop/Appland/Project.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ImageTk
ImportError: No module named ImageTk

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`ImageTk` is a part of the `PIL` module.

You need to use `from PIL import ImageTk`

You'll also want to save a reference to your image. Here's one example.

```
 photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Logo.png")
 root.image = photoimage
 canvas_image = canvas.create_image(150, 150, image=root.image)
```

Comment: That's also one of my problems, when im trying to use 'from PIL import ImageTk' so it says: 'No module named PIL'

Comment: Then you should probably install PIL. `pip install pillow`

Comment: How do i do that? to enter it in the code?

Comment: In the shell / command prompt / cmd.